# Angular directive not getting updated controller data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form where one of the selects is a field that the data comes from an array generated by the backend.

The issue I have is the controller has an empty array to store the data. 
This array then gets populated by the request to the backend. The only issue is the directive is not using the updated data it only uses the empty array that is created on the controller.

I have used this directive from the attached plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/J7bQoSKe17VQ5i6RPxps?p=info

The setTimeout is acting like my ajax call.

```
     //Very big arry that will become all the available choices.
  vm.allItems = [];

  // 'Loaded' after time to act like async ajax request to server.
  setTimeout(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 9500; i++) {
    var person = {
      name: 'Adam' + i,
      email: 'adam' + i + '@email.com',
      age: 12,
      country: 'United States'
    };
    vm.allItems.push(person);
    }  
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Loaded: ' + vm.allItems[4].name + ' and others.';
  }, 1500);
```

I was just testing with updating the status element to see when the data should be present.

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues.

First:

```
 vm.multipleDemo.selectedPeople = [vm.allItems[500], vm.allItems[4]];
```

Is called before the timeout triggers so both values are null.

Second:
You need to change setTimeout to use $timeout. The result should be:

```
$timeout(function(){
for (var i = 0; i < 9500; i++) {
var person = {
  name: 'Adam' + i,
  email: 'adam' + i + '@email.com',
  age: 12,
  country: 'United States'
};
vm.allItems.push(person);
}
 vm.multipleDemo.selectedPeople = [vm.allItems[500], vm.allItems[4]];
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Loaded: ' + vm.allItems[4].name + ' and others.';
  }, 1500);
```

$timeout works much like setTimeout but it wraps the callback function in a $apply which ensures that changes are seen by angular.

You havent posted your AJAX request, but you should look at $http for making your requests, this will mean that the result will be seen by angular. 
See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thanks for looking through my code Tim. Being fairly new to angular I really appreciate it.

Thanks for the $timeout tip. Was only using that to test in the plunkr anyway.  The plunkr seems to be working but when I change to my code code a few things happen.

I have used $http in the factory/service that I made to do the ajax call.
`  getAll: function() {
              return $http.get(CONFIG.BASE_API_URL + "all");
            }
` That works fine.

Comment: In my view if I just 'log' the outcome of the ajax call with something like 
`{{ allItems }} ` then I see the output come through to the view. My directive that takes allItems as an input `<ui-select-choices allchoices="allItems" ...</ui-select-choices>` never uses the updated array.

Any ideas, was wondering about some kind of scope? Maybe...